# How to access text of a label in a UICollectionViewCell from a different method?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath, textlabel

I have a class of type `UICollectionViewController`. In this class I have variable for the label of a `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
var cellTitle = UILabel()
```

I also have the collectionView method `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    var definitions = shuffle(["Used to carry the pharoah","Used to carry bodies as a ceremony","Had a flat deck to carry a farmer's treasure","Daily, it made a trip around the world to carry Ra","Towed by smaller boats, carrying heavy objects","Used for business and pleasure by officials/nobles","Carried most Egyptians and some goods"])
    var boatTypes = shuffle(["Ferry","Funeral Barge","Cargo Boat","Cattle Boat","Royal Boat","The Sun Boat","Grand Boat"])
    // Configure the cell
    cellTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 160))
    cell.contentView.addSubview(cellTitle)
switch indexPath.item {
    case 0:
        cellTitle.text = definitions[0]
    case 1:
        cellTitle.text = definitions[1]
    case 2:
        cellTitle.text = definitions[2]
    case 3:
        cellTitle.text = definitions[3]
    case 4:
        cellTitle.text = definitions[4]
    case 5:
        cellTitle.text = definitions[5]
    case 6:
        cellTitle.text = definitions[6]
    case 7:
        cellTitle.text = boatTypes[0]
    case 8:
        cellTitle.text = boatTypes[1]
    case 9:
        cellTitle.text = boatTypes[2]
    case 10:
        cellTitle.text = boatTypes[3]
    case 11:
        cellTitle.text = boatTypes[4]
    case 12:
        cellTitle.text = boatTypes[5]
    case 13:
        cellTitle.text = boatTypes[6]
    default:
        break
```

I also have a `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedText = cellTitle.text
    switch indexPath.item {
    case 0:
        if selectedText == "Used to carry the pharoah" {
            println("Used to carry the pharoah")
        } else {
            println("Not Working")
        }
```

The problem is that when I press the cell that the label does have the text "Used to carry the pharoah", `println("Not Working")` is triggered. How can I pass the value from the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method to the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method so the value of `cellTitle` stays the same? Thank you.

Comment: You can to use the `indexPath` that was passed to the function to retrieve the cell, but don't do this.  Rather, use the indexPath to go directly to your data model (the array in this case) - but you should move the array out of the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function - it is very inefficient to keep redefining the array.  Also you can replace that list of case statements with a single if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cellForItemAtIndexPath is called for each item when it is to be displayed. You are applying some sort of a "shuffle" on the array of string? So, not all strings will necessarily be used and a few will be have same text.
You can simply have the variables 'definitions' and 'boats' globally initialized and then access the value like this:

```
if indexPath.item < 7 {
    selectedText = definitions[indexPath.item]
} else {
    selectedText = boatTypes[indexPath.item]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem! Much less coding too :)